# Sumar valores entre el rango de un dia

Tags: php, mysql, sum

tengo la siguiente duda.

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT linea, fecha, noparte, total,
        sum(total) AS TotalAS
        FROM scrap.registro
        WHERE fecha>= '2020-11-01'  AND fecha<= '2020-11-30' AND linea = 'L-02 (SMT)'
        group by fecha
```

**Con el siguiente resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero obtener es el total por dia, digamos que me sume lo del dia 02 de noviembre puse el **group by**, pero no me suma en un solo registro el dia.

Mi intencion es generar una grafica de esto, pero solo necesito obtener la suma por dia de estos datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo deja el campo fecha y total en el select. Al campo fecha hay que cambiarle formato para quitar las horas para que agrupe correctamente.

```
 SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y/%m/%d') as fecha, sum(total) AS TotalAS
 FROM scrap.registro
 WHERE fecha>= '2020-11-01'  AND fecha<= '2020-11-30' AND linea = 'L-02 (SMT)'
 group by DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

---

Cuando se hacen comparaciones de fechas hay que prestar atención si las fechas también incluyen horas porque al comparar las fechas se toma como hora la media noche de ese día.

Por ejemplo:

```
fecha <= '2020-11-30'
```

Ese rango incluye las fechas que sean menores a `'2020-11-30 12:00:00'`, si hay un registro con fecha `'2020-11-30 08:00:00'` ( el mismo día  las 8 de la mañana ) no se incluirá en los resultados.

En el rango superior deben incluirse las horas:

```
fecha <= '2020-11-30 23:59:59'
```

O hacerlo menor que el día siguiente del final del rango:

```
fecha < '2020-12-01'
```

O cualquier forma válida para incluir las horas del último día del rango.

Comment: Gracias, funciona correctamente :')

Comment: Discupa amigo, como puedo hacer para que el dia que no hubo nada salga en ceros?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Me genera un conflicto por que en tu consulta no viene el dato "linea" y cuando especifico la linea en el WHERE ya no me trae los dias con valor 0